# How does the '\b' character in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell

Source: Hutton, Graham. "*Programming in Haskell*" (p. 180)

> 6. Using `getCh`, define an action `readLine :: IO String` that behaves in the same way as getLine, except that it also permits the delete key to be used to remove characters.

> Hint: the delete character is `’\ DEL’`, and the control character for moving the cursor back one space is `’\b’`.

I solved this exercise using one `'\b'` character, but found online that a solver used two. Why the solver of this problem uses `"\b \b"` instead of `"\b"` ? Seems like a typo but I am unsure. I have found it works with three `'\b'` characters.

How does this character work ?

```hs
import System.IO

getCh :: IO Char
getCh = do
  hSetEcho stdin False
  x <- getChar
  hSetEcho stdin True
  return x

readLine :: IO String
readLine = readLine' ""

readLine' :: String -> IO String
readLine' xs = do
  x <- getCh
  case x of
    '\n' -> do
      putChar '\n'
      return xs
    '\DEL' ->
      if null xs
        then readLine' ""
        else do
          putStr "\b \b"
          readLine' (init xs)
    _ -> do
      putChar x
      readLine' (xs ++ [x])
```

Comment: Note that `\b` is really just a character like any other; Haskell itself doesn't assign it any special meaning. It's your *terminal* that "displays" the character by moving the cursor rather than printing some other visible glyph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use just `"\b"`, the cursor goes to the left but doesn't delete the character seen there until you overwrite it with a new key input. For example, <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> will end you up with `fo⁁o`, but that's misleading: if you *don't* hit another letter key but immediately <kbd>↵</kbd>, then it'll seem that the result is still `foo`, when actually it's only `fo`.

To avoid this, the solution `"\b \b"` moves to the left, overwrites the character with a space to visualise deleting it, and immediately moves to the left again. Together this has the same effect as moving left once and deleting the character there in-place.

Comment: What's the name of the key after "if you don't hit another letter key but immediately..." ?

Comment: Enter / return.

Answer (score 6):

`\b` moves the cursor one character back, but it doesn't erase it (at least, not on most terminals). For example, the string `abcde\b` will be displayed as `abcde`, and the string `abcde\bf` as `abcdf`. That's why the sequence `\b \b` explicitly overwrites the last character with a space, and then moves the cursor back again.

Comment: +1. Thank you. When you say "the string abcde\b will be displayed as abcde", does the character trigger a cursor move ? How does that work ?

Comment: @F.Zer yes, this character (with the corresponding code 8), when sent to a terminal, tells it to move the cursor back.